# Parameters are not working passing to a crystal reports from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I am using this code to pass parameters to my crystal report, but in run time crystal report is showing text boxes to input parameters. please help me to solve this

```
Dim rpt As New RPT_Maintenance
rpt.SetDataSource(maintenanceDetailsTable)
rpt.SetParameterValue("datefrom", dtpDateFrom.Text)
rpt.SetParameterValue("dateto", DtpDateTo.Text)
rpt.SetParameterValue("cat", "All Vehicles")
FRM_ReportViewer.CrystelReportViewer.ReportSource = rpt
FRM_ReportViewer.ShowDialog()
FRM_ReportViewer.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

If the parameter box keep popping up, what you can do is on the page load of your crystal report viewer form, paste this:

```
Dim param1Fields As New ParameterFields
Dim param1Field As New ParameterField
Dim param1Range As New ParameterDiscreteValue

param1Field.ParameterFieldName = "TeamRoster"
param1Range.Value = Roster.cmbTeams.Text
param1Field.CurrentValues.Add(param1Range)
param1Fields.Add(param1Field)
CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = param1Fields
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to set Datasource to report before settings parameter like.

```
reportClass.SetDataSource(source);

reportClass.SetParameterValue("txtCompanyName", companyName);

viewer.SetReportSource(reportClass);
```

Comment: yes i am doing this already. like rpt.setDatasource(maintenanceDatatable). but not working ..